# How to get friends posts on my facebook wall using graph API for iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using below code(Graph API) to parse my facebook feed....

```
    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me/feed" withGetVars:nil]; 
    SBJSON *_jsonparsing=[[SBJSON alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *_dict=[_jsonparsing objectWithString:fb_graph_response.htmlResponse error:nil];
    NSDictionary *_dict1=[_dict objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"CHECK____ %@", _dict1);
```

Here, I didn't get the posts that my friends posted on my wall. Even I didn't get the texts what I've posted. Only the links, files & photos I got what I've posted on my wall. How can I get my friends posts and my text posts on my wall ???..please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you didn't ask for `read_stream` permission.. Did you?

Comment: That's the permission you need in order to read the user's wall. You need to ask for it when asking the user to login. If you want clarification - paste the code that you used for the login.